# Inserting into db using class with value ERROR

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, dropdown

I created a 2 dropdown box that has same value and added a class for my javascript inorder to disable the value that is selected on each other dropdown 
By using this code I can insert the data but my javascript wont work

```
 <option value="<?= $coa->id ?>"><?= $coa->firstName?> <?= $coa->lastName?></option>
```

This one javascript works but cant insert to db gives me **Notice: Undefined index:asst_coach1**  and  **Undefined index:asst_coach2**

```
<option value="<?= $coa->id ?>"><?= $coa->firstName?> <?= $coa->lastName?></option>
```

JS Code

```
$('.ddb').change(function(e){
var val = $(this).val();
// reenable previous select
$('.'+$(e.target).attr('data-pre')).removeAttr('disabled');
// disable new select
$('.'+val).attr("disabled", "disabled");
// update prevouse select
$(e.target).attr('data-pre',val);   
});
```

PS : And if you have also other idea on how to disable the selected value on the other dropdown box is also welcome. Help cheers!

Answer (score 0):

To hide it, wrap it with a span tag.

```
$( "#selectlist option[value=4]" ).wrap( "<span>" );
```

To show it, unwrap the span tag if it has one.

```
if ( $( "#selectlist option[value=4]" ).parent().is( "span" ) ){
$( "#selectlist option[value=4]" ).unwrap();}
```

or

```
var i = $('option:selected', this).index();
$(" option:lt("+ i +")").hide();
```